# applicationDidBecomeActive runs after ViewController loaded

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io

I'm using socket.io to use the real-time mechanism. Problem that I'm facing right now is that Socket.io's object created after the viewController is loaded

I'm using Singleton design

```
import SocketIO

class SocketIOManager: NSObject {

    static let sharedInstance = SocketIOManager()

    var socket: SocketIOClient!

    func establishConnection() {
       socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: URL(string: mainURL)!, config: [.log(false), .compress, .connectParams(["token": "asdasdasdsa"])])
       socket.connect()

    }

    func closeConnection() {
        socket.disconnect()
    }

}
```

I need to set the socket in the establishConnection no matter what to make sure that user has establish the connection to the server together with the token. If I follow Vlad's answer, the connection will be never be established because the token is empty before hand thus user won't get connected.

User logs in

```
func logIn() {
   // Getting it from alamofire
   keychain["token"] = token
   //then only establish connection
   SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.establishConnection()
}
```

If I use Init method then the `socket` will be nil because in the `applicationDidBecomeActive` there's the `SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.establishConnection()`, so the logic is whenever user loads up the app the `applicationDidBecomeActive` will run

so technically I'm using `sharedInstance` to run the socket.io object.

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.establishConnection()
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }
```

Right now the socket object in the didBecomeActive runs after the view loaded

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    listeningOnMerchant()

}

func listeningOnMerchant() {
   // I got error around here
   SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.socket.on("listening") { ack, data in
      print("something")


   }
  }
}
```

Which will crash because `socket` is nil. How do I make the viewController not crash. I could use the `let` method to stop the crash

```
if let socket = SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.socket {

}
```

But it will be nil if I use `socket` and socket won't be running. How do I not make the socket not crash?

Because i really need to put the `socket.connect` on `applicationDidBecomeActive` to make it consistent as in the connection vs `didLaunch`

Thanks!

Comment: if you already using singleton, why don't you put initialisation of socket inside this singleton?

Comment: initialization can only called in the `establishConnection` function for a specific reason.

Comment: I edited my question already

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question directly but why can't you just initialize the socket if it's nil before trying to call `.on`

Answer (score 2):

Technically to solve this problem you need to use the `init` method so that the socket won't be nil. Since you need the socket to be running when the app paused and so on, you need to use the init method no matter what.

```
   private override init() {
        self.socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: URL(string: mainURL)!, config: [.log(true), .compress, .forceNew(true), .connectParams(["token": getToken()])])
        super.init()
    }
```

Add `forceNew(true)` so that you won't create multiple connections for one user

The next step you need to do is to create another function that only your loginViewController can access

```
 func establishConnectionWhenLogin(_ token: String) {
        self.socket =  SocketIOClient(socketURL: URL(string: mainURL)!, config: [.log(false), .compress, .connectParams(["token": token])])
        socket.connect()

    }
```

pass the token to the parameter so that only user has logged in then you want to establish the connection. If you have any problems let me know

I use this solution for my own app and it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, your problem is in setting **SocketIOClient** at the **establishConnection** func. If it crashes with nil, probably your constructor returns nil here:

```
SocketIOClient(socketURL: URL(string: mainURL)!, config: [.log(false), .compress, .connectParams(["token": "asdasdasdsa"])])
```

I don't see a reason also to do this inside this func. It's easy to make a mistake and leave **socket** var uninitialised at some point. I would rather make it let and set it inside of constructor, something like this:

```
import SocketIO

class SocketIOManager: NSObject {

    static let sharedInstance = SocketIOManager()

    let socket: SocketIOClient!

    init() {
        super.init()
        socket = YourFixedConstructorHere()
    }
}
```

If you want to make sure it's initialised, you can also make it lazy var, like this:

```
lazy var socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: URL(string: mainURL)!, config: [.log(false), .compress, .connectParams(["token": "asdasdasdsa"])])
```

Comment: Thanks Vlad for taking your time to answer my question

Comment: Which approach do you think is suitable for my use case?

Comment: lazy or using init() Thanks!

Comment: @sinusGob, I would initialise it inside of init. it's a safer way.

lazy could be used, if SocketIOClient creation is not cheap

Comment: Btw Vlad, I really need to set the socket at the establishConnection because if I don't do that then whenever user logs in the connection be created if I used your method because of the getToken func

Comment: I'm updating the question

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is a timing problem. You should call your singleton BEFORE the ViewController did load the view. So you better put this code

```
SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.establishConnection()
```

into a function (that is performed earlier) in AppDelegate

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

         SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.establishConnection()

    return true
}
```

Comment: What you said is correct, but what if the application paused, I definitely need to put that in `didApplicationBecomeActive` I tried that solution before and it works, except when I put the application in the background or if the application paused then that would be a problem.

Comment: I can't put both in the `didBecomeActive` and `didFinishLaunching` that would create 2 connections per user which is not practical , if I have more than 200 users, it could cause a lot of problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, at some point you can't use **establishConnection()** because you lack the token. This logic doesn't entirely fit with your singleton pattern, as your object's responsibility is only to establish / cancel connection and it already can't do that after instance created. I would rather use service here, like this:

```
class SocketIOService {
    let token: String // I think if token is related to SocketIO, you can store it here
    init(token: String) {
        self.token = token
    }
    // Your code to establish connections, etc
}
```

This way you would guaranty, that your entire service can't be created without token. Pretty better, as for me

Options with singleton pattern are not so good, but they definitely existed. First, you can add parameter to your method:

```
func establishConnection(withToken token: String) {
    // code
}
```

With this method, you will require token to be passed in, so without it user won't be able to establish connection.

Then, wherever you want to use it you can do like this:

```
if let token = // Your code to retrieve token {
    SocketIOManager.shared.establishConnection(withToken: token)
}
```

or even:

```
keychain["token"].flatMap {SocketIOManager.shared.establishConnection(withToken: $0)}
```

Pretty nice, huh?

There several other ways of doing this, but with all them your workflow is almost the same - at first you check, if you have a token, then you call this method. If you not succeed - after you retrieve token, try again.

Comment: Thank you again Vlad, I need to try this out

Comment: Just wondering is this solution still a singleton design? because You are creating a new class SocketIOService?

Comment: For socket.io it is better to create a singleton design so that you don't spawn many connections. Thus why I incorporated the Singleton design

Comment: There's a tutorial by Twillio people https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/09/getting-started-with-socket-io-in-swift-on-ios.html if you scroll down, they even use this singleton design

Comment: Let me know what you think

Comment: and One more think your solution for the `establishConnection` won't work because whenever the app loads up, the init method  will initialize the socket object without the token. And Singleton design only can be initialized one time, doesn't matter if I have the token or not, it won't connect because the init method already initialized it without the token

Comment: This only happen when user is logging in. User logs in and then he gets the token from the server, once token is there then only `establishConnection` which won't work because init already runs when the app loads up